# SQL SERVER transaction log restore

Tags: sql-server

We have a local SQL SERVER database , which is used to sync a third party SQL SERVER database everyday. They provide us transaction log file daily, and a full backup file every weekend.
For example we get a full backup file Sun.bak on Sunday,
and Monday get Mon.trn, Tuesday get tue.trn and so on

My understanding is in order to restore the transaction log backup file,
everyday, I need to restore the full backup first, and then the following transaction log file(s).

Such as on Monday, I need to restore Sun.bak + Mon.trn to restore it, and on Tuesday I need to restore Sun.bak+Mon.trn+Tue.trn

I would like to know if its possible to skip the full backup step and only restore the transaction log file ? Such as on Wednesday, I only restore Wed.trn, is that possible?

Comment: The first question is what happens every morning? Do you restore the database and then put it online in order to use it?

Answer (score 1):

That will not work. A Transaction log backup contains all the **changes** made to the database since the last Complete backup. The changes alone will not work, you also need to have a record of what is being changed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so you are saying that all sql server restore must start from a full backup restore in the first place. Am I right?